# union of two subspace of non-maximal dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $U,V$ two dimension $n-1$ subspace of $F^n$ where $F$ is an infinite field, then I want to show that $U\cup V$ does not exhaust the whole space. It is very clear intuitively, but I cannot find a short argument that nails it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\;U\subset V\;\;or\;\;V\subset U\;$ then the claim's clear, so assume

$$\begin{cases}U\rlap{\;\,/}\subset V\implies \exists u\in U\setminus V\\V\rlap{\;\,/}\subset U\implies \exists v\in V\setminus U\end{cases}$$

Well, since $\;u+v\in F^n\;$ , it must be that $\;u+v\in U\cup V\;$ . Show now that either possibility leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

If $U = V$, then $U\cup V = U \neq F^n$. If $U\neq V$, we have $U\not\subset V$ and $V\not\subset U$. Pick $u \in U\setminus V$ and $v\in V\setminus U$. What can you say about $u+v$?